# Eclipse JRE Definition not including core classes

Tags: eclipse, java

I am trying to lnclude an additional JDK (really JRE) to my eclipse project as i need to build against the IBM Java 5 JRE.

When I add the root folder of the jre it appears as if the core java class jars are not being added and only the jars in \lib\ext are being added.  That is problem 1.

The next issues is I can't even manually add the jars by adding external jars to the runtime library.  The reason being when I hit ok to save off the changes and then hit ok to the preferences dialog.  The changes do not truly save.  I open up the jre definition dialog again and only the jars in \lib\ext are there again.

Is this an eclipse bug?  Is anybody finding similar results?

I'd really like to figure out where these preferences are stored so I can manually edit the file if need be.

As a side note, I have had a similar experience with not being able to save .pmd rule preferences and having to edit them manually in the backend.  Though I suspect that bug is on the PMD developers.

Anyway any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.